# stringify-object crashed the test

Tags: jestjs, stringify

Every time a test is calling the method stringifyObject from the npm modul stringify-object with an object the test crash with follow exception:

> TypeError: get_own_enumerable_property_symbols_1.default.default is not a function or its return value is not iterable

```
336 |
337 |   const obj = { status: 400, data: { code: 400, message: 'Test'} };
338 |   const log = stringifyObject(obj);
>   |               ^
```

with a simply data type like string or number the test works fine. Here the example code

//functions.ts

```
import stringifyObject from 'stringify-object';

export function traceError() {
const obj = { status: 400, data: { code: 400, message: 'Test'} };
const log = stringifyObject(obj);
console.log(log);
return obj;
}
```

//functions.test.ts

```
import { traceError } from 'functions';

describe('functions', () =\> {
test('traceError should return 400', () =\> {
const response = traceError();
expect(response.status).toEqual(400);
});
```

Any solution for this?

I checked already, that with simply types like string or number the test works fine

```
const obj = 'this is a test';
const log = stringifyObject(obj);
```

I use in my project jest 28.1.0. I try with the newest 29.3.1, too. The same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. I use instead of

```
const log = stringifyObject(obj);
```

this code

```
const json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, '\t');
const unquoted = json.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '$1:');
```

Answer (score 0):

This was [fixed](https://github.com/yeoman/stringify-object/issues/77) in `stringify-object@5.0.0`.